# How to know when an async func has finished c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, webclient

I download many urls from the web but I don't know when all the urls have been finished to download. Meanwhile I wrote something, but it seem too me a trash although it works.

In my code I download all the urls from `dtPP` dataTable and save them to `matUrlFharsing` array.

Here is my code:

```
main()
{
    Parallel.For(0, dtPP.Rows.Count, i =>
    {
         string f = "";
         WebClient client = new WebClient();
         client.DownloadDataCompleted += new DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadDataCompleted);
         lock (dtPP.Rows[i])
         {
              f = dtPP.Rows[i]["pp_url"].ToString();
         }
         client.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(f), i);
    });
    while (end)
    {
    }
    DoSomething();
 }


void client_DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            int h = (int)e.UserState;
            page = (int)e.UserState;
            myString = enc.GetString(e.Result);

            lock (matUrlFharsing[h])
            {
                lock (dtPP.Rows[h])
                {
                    //save in mat
                    matUrlFharsing[h] = Pharsing.CreateCorrectHtmlDoc(myString);
                }
            }

            lock (myLocker)
            {
                ezer = false;
                for (int j = 0; j < matUrlFharsing.Length && !ezer; j++)
                {
                    if (matUrlFharsing[j] == "")
                        ezer = true;
                }
                end = ezer;
            }
        }
```

What can I do to improve or change it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Small improvement:

Use [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) instead of bool for End.

```
AutoResetEvent autoResetEvent;

main()
{
    autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    Parallel.For(0, dtPP.Rows.Count, i =>
    {
        // your code
    });
    autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
    DoSomething();
 }

void client_DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   ...
   if(ezer)
   {
       autoResetEvent.Set();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array of AutoResetEvent, send them to event receiver as parameter and wait them all.

```
AutoResetEvent[] autoResetEvents;
main()
{
    autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent[dtPP.Rows.Count];
    Parallel.For(0, dtPP.Rows.Count, i =>
    {
         string f = "";
         WebClient client = new WebClient();
         client.DownloadDataCompleted += new DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadDataCompleted);
         lock (dtPP.Rows[i])
         {
              f = dtPP.Rows[i]["pp_url"].ToString();
         }
         Object[] parameters = new Object[2];
         autoResetEvents[i] = new AutoResetEvent(false);
         parameters[0] = i;
         parameters[1] = autoResetEvent[i];

         client.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(f), parameters);
    });
    WaitHandle.WaitAll(autoResetEvents);
    DoSomething();
 }

    void client_DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Object[] parameters = (object[])e.UserState;
        autoResetEvent = (AutoResetEvent)parameters[1];
        int h = (int)parameters[0];
        page = (int)e.UserState;
        myString = enc.GetString(e.Result);

        lock (matUrlFharsing[h])
        {
            lock (dtPP.Rows[h])
            {
                //save in mat
                matUrlFharsing[h] = Pharsing.CreateCorrectHtmlDoc(myString);
            }
        }
        autoResetEvent.Set();
    }
```

Comment: What the main difference from your first answer?

Comment: In my first answer i sugested, that you manually check whether all data downloaded and then send signal to main thread. Here i sugest to use  AutoResetEvent for each downloading and in main thread wait signals from all of them

Comment: Check if all your data downloaded every time is not good, so this answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

The completed event is called when the async function is finished. You are in the right path...

You can improve you code in the While (end). This While statement will run very fast. You can:

- You can a sleep 1s to reduce CPU processing.
- You can put a timeout in the while to make sure the application is not locked.